# Conditional Density of an Exponential Given Gamma

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, gamma-distribution, exponential-distribution

> Suppose $X, Y$ are iid. $\exp(2)$. Let $T$ = $X + Y$. Find $f_x (x | T = t)$.

This is a problem from a practice exam. I know that $T\sim\mathrm{Gamma}(2, 2)$ since $T$ is a sum of 2 independent exponentials with the same rate (2). But, I'm a bit stuck on finding the conditional density. I tried using Bayes' Rule, but the calculations seem to be way too complicated, since the professor mentioned the calculations shouldn't be too bad. What is the "smart" way of solving this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: The canonical method to find the _joint_ pdf of $X$ and $T=X+Y$ from the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$: determining the latter is easy via iid. Exp(2), while for the former you might need to call on the dreaded Jacobian formula. Then, divide the joint pdf of $X$ and $T$ by the _marginal_ distribution of $T$ (which you say you know) to get the conditional pdf of $X$ given that $T = t$.  Be careful with matters such as the value of $T$ must always be at least as large as the value of $X$ which affects things like the _support_ of the joint pdf of $X$ and $T$.

Answer (score 3):

Now that this is a few months old, I'm going to assume it is safe to answer without advantaging you unfairly in your exam.  Letting $\beta$ be the rate parameter for your problem, for all $0 \leqslant x \leqslant t$ you have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
f_{X|T}(x|t) = \frac{f_{X,T}(x,t)}{f_{T}(t)} 
&= \frac{f_{X}(x) f_{Y}(t-x)}{f_{T}(t)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\beta \exp (- \beta x) \cdot \beta \exp ( - \beta (t-x))}{\beta^2 t \exp(- \beta t)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{t}. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

So you have the distributional form $X|T \sim \text{U}(0, T)$.  In other words, once $T$ is known, the value $X$ is uniformly distributed over the range of allowable values.  As you can see, this result is actually independent of the rate parameter in your question.